# Copy data from many files to master based on cell values in the master

Tags: excel, vba

First time poster here.

I have a list of files (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`) and I want to copy a range from those files into a master file. The master file contains a column with this data `file1`, `file2`, `file3`. How can I loop through that column and copy and paste each file's range into the corresponding row in the master? I need the data from `file1` to go into a range in the same row as `file1`.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim col As Range

Dim cell As Range
Dim currentRow As Long

Dim varCellValue As String

Dim pasteRangeC As String
Dim pasteRangeE As String



Set col = Range("B3:B5")
currentRow = 3

 For Each cell In col


    varCellValue = cell.Value
    currentRow = 3

    pasteRangeC = "C" & currentRow
    pasteRangeE = "E" & currentRow


    '## Open workbooks:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\" & varCellValue &_ ".xlsx")
    Set y = ThisWorkbook


    'Copy from x:
    x.Sheets("Summary").Range("D13:F13").Copy


    'Paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(pasteRangeC & ":" & pasteRangeE).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Close x:
    x.Close
    currentRow = currentRow + 1

 Next


End Sub
```

The code works for the first loop then I get a run-time error 1004 that the file cannot be found. So I'm thinking the `varCellValue` does not get the next cell's value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: one thing I see is that you need to remove the `currentRow = 3` that is inside the `For` block. That is resetting the variable `currentRow` to 3 everytime and negating the latter `currentRow = currentRow +1` statement.  Are you sure that File2 is a valid path and that everything is spelled correctly to pick up the file path and file name?

Comment: Did you step through the code and see what `varCellValue` is after the 2nd loop?

Comment: Scott and Dave,Thanks for the replies!
Scott - currentRow was inside the loop and I put it outside. Didn't realize I still had it in the loop also until I read your comment. Now everything works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read try the following

```
Option Explicit 'Use every time will keep you from making simple mistakes...
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrCatch 'add to catch errors
Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 1 To 5

    '## Open workbooks:
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xlsx") 'Cells(Row,Column) 2 = "B"

    'Copy from wbSource and paste in worksheet
    wbSource.Sheets("Summary").Range("D13:F13").Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(i, 3)  'This syntax keeps you from having to do "Application.CutCopyMode = False" to remove the marching ants.

    'Close source:
    wbSource.Close False
 Next i

ErrCatch:
If Err.Number > 1 Then 'test if an error was thrown
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```